# to "freeze on" somebody

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, verbs, lyrics

In Kate Bush's song *Babooshka*, we can hear these lines right before the second chorus:

> Uncanny how she
>   Reminds him of his little lady
>   Capacity to give him all he needs
>   Just like his wife before she **freezed on** him
>   Just like his wife when she was beautiful

What does this mean? I know that to "freeze *out*" is the same as to ignore somebody, but I'm guessing this is not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe "she freezed" here is a nonstandard way to say "she froze", as in to become frigid (abnormally averse to sexual intercourse — used especially of women, per Merriam-Webster). "On him" is just an idiomatic way to say that something happened to someone, like "the battery died on me." In that case the battery simply stopped working, with no implication of where it happened.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean to become frigid. That is very strong. If you become frigid, it is not just for one man. It more likely means she was just turned off by the guy. Yes,freezed is pretty awful for froze.

Comment: Kate Bush's [choice of words is never awful](https://genius.com/Kate-bush-sunset-lyrics). English grammar adjusts to comply with her lyrics.